# React Native - Is extending a class acceptable in this scenario?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I have read multiple times: Composition is Good. Extending is Evil.

Now, I do use composition, basically a lot of stateless components and higher order components, however I do have one particular case where I extend a class.

Instead of every stateless component extending from Component, I am extending from my own BaseComponent, which basically has some helper functions that I use in all of my components.

Like for example:

- Analytics helpers
- Loggers
- Data Fetchers
- Configuration
- Storage
- Theme management
- Actions

So far, I am happy with the result. I am looking for any good reason for me to actually break this pattern in the objective to pursuit great code.

Please no "React recommends composition" answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well why not simply use HOC's for each of those pieces?

The big benefit of using HOC's for these kind of situations, is that you can apply them individually, or as a group.  You gain a ton of control in how you slice/dice these shared pieces of functionality.

As a simple, example, your logger as an HOC might look something like;

```
const function loggerHoc(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends Component {
        log(message) {
            console.log(message); //or other implementation
        }

        render() {
            <WrappedComponent log={this.log} {...this.props}/>;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you had a second HOC of this style for analytics, they can be wrapped on top of one another without issue;

```
ResultComponent = loggerHoc(analyticsHoc(ChildComponent));
```

Which you could also write a function to do all of;

```
const function wrapWithAll(WrappedComponent) {
    return loggerHoc(
        analyticsHoc(
            WrappedComponent
        )
    );
}
```

Or you can use individually, as your needs dictate.

Comment: I was actually thinking about something like this, however none of my re usable pieces are UI based, so maybe I was thinking about making it a core module and just import them on each component. I do like your approach tho.

Comment: Instead of HOC I was thinking about composing, which is basically the same.